# how can I load values from App.config in c# using .Net Framework 4 Client Profile

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I'm having difficulty getting my settings out of App.config. The research I've done so far says that I should be able to use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings (which is part of System.Configuration).

However, I can't get it to compile. And of course it doesn't like the older method (ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings) either as its obsolete.

What have I missed here?

Is it my project's Target Framework (currently set to ".Net Framework 4 Client Profile
")?

And example of my code follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;

namespace myNameSpace
{
    class Program
    {

        private void LoadAppConfig()
        {
            string mySetting;

            //This won't compile
            mySetting = 
                System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                                                    .AppSettings["mySettingName"];

            //This compiles but of course is obsolete, and I get that warning.
            mySetting = 
                System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings
                                                    .AppSettings["mySettingName"];
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // stuff happens
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the reference?

Comment: What specific error message are you getting?

Comment: @SpikeX  A closer look at the error message on my would have given me that clue that I needed from leppie. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a reference to [System.Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.aspx)